# jquery fancybox in that i have one textarea i want to populate some text in that textarea but it is shows in second click populated not in first click

Tags: jquery

```
$('#ancFC[rel*=facybox]').facybox().click(function () {
    $(".showSelectedChoice").html(Choicename);
    $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFC").html(desc); // here i am assing my value to 
       //textarea but in first click it is not showing .it is show in second click 
 });
```

Comment: can you post the relevant html ?

Comment: why did my edit got rejected ? :s

Answer (score 1):

You have written `facybox` instead of `fancybox`. That is probably one of your issues.